# How to call a virtual void function C++?

Tags: c++, function, linker-errors

I came across an exercise that I found online. 
This exercise consist of "virtual void" that I never seen before of how it works. 
So the exercise contain 1 header file named plans.h

```
namespace plans {

class HumanActions {
public:
  virtual void goTo() { }
  virtual void haveANiceColdBeer() { }
};

void applyPlan(HumanActions &actions);

}
```

and one cpp file

```
#include "Plans.h"

using plans::HumanActions;
using plans::applyPlan;

void
plans::applyPlan(HumanActions &actions) {
  actions.goTo();
  actions.haveANiceColdBeer();
}
```

I tried to run the function by having another main file that runs like

```
#include "Plans.h"

using plans::HumanActions;
using plans::applyPlan;

int main() {
    HumanActions actions;
    applyPlan(actions);
}
```

Unfortunately it does not run and it says that I have undefined reference to `plans::applyPlan(plans::Actions&)' so My question is how do you pass the functions for those argument given?

Comment: virtual functions should be actually created on the subclass to be used and cannot be used like that so you need to create a sublcass, fill the functions and then use it.

Comment: its return nothing at all

Comment: Did you link both *.cpp files into one program?

Comment: no. I have saparate main.cpp

Comment: I suggest you separate your two problems: 1) put all the code above into one .cpp file (in the order you've posted it, with all `#include "Plans.h"` removed.  Get it working by fixing the problem with differing argument types for `applyPlan` per existing answers' advice.  Then after the virtual dispatch aspect's working you can split the file again if you want to, and if it doesn't work look for existing answers about unresolved references.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared "void applyPlan(HumanActions &actions)" in the header file, but you have not defined (implemented) it anywhere, which is why you have the undefined symbol.

If in main(), you called applyZombiePlan() instead of applyPlan() you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

"Undefined reference" is a linker error that means the implementation for a function couldn't be found.  In other words, it typically means you declared the function, and called the function, but forgot to actually *write* the function.

Your error message refers to `plans::applyPlan(plans::Actions&)`, but the closest declaration I see is `void applyPlan(HumanActions &actions);`, which has a different argument type.  Assuming this isn't just a mix-up between different versions of the code in your post, you might have accidentally declared two different `applyPlan` functions but only implemented one of them.

If your program consists of more than one `.cpp` file, another possible reason is that you're accidentally trying to compile *and link* a single file as if it were a complete program instead of linking all the modules together.  That'd make the linker not see anything defined in the other `.cpp` files.  If you're a beginner, your best bet is to compile all your source files at once with a single command line, e.g. `g++ *.cpp -o myprog`.

Calling a virtual function is no different from calling a regular function, BTW, and `applyPlan` is not a virtual function anyway.

Comment: Thanks!!
I have 2 cpp file and run it using "g++ main.cpp" and tried your method but sill give me the same exact issues.
it says in main.cpp so i am guessing Im not calling the functions right.

Comment: I dont think its the compiler issue. I just give it a go. Thanks tho

Comment: Well, it's definitely a problem.  It might not be the *only* problem, but `g++ main.cpp` will completely ignore the contents of `plans.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of extern keyword. whenever you are actually defining your global function, you can say void XYZ(){} and everywhere else you can say extern void XYZ().